# Action based on page content

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Is there any way of creating a scrapy rule based on content of page? The reason being is I am trying to create a crawler for a website which has a certain page that is displayed but the URL doesn't change, so I need the spider to recognize it is on that page from the content and then call a certain function.

Comment: Kindly provide more info, such as HTML content, and what should happen if something is available in that content and what should not.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html